# python-flask how to generate a boolean list in a form

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

Ok I get the basics of the Form, View, HTML template for generating a form where you would go:

```
class General_Form(Form):
    yes_no = BooleanField('well?', default = False)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Form.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def validate(self):
        if not Form.validate(self):
            return False
    return True
```

and if I passed General_Form over to my view as a form object I would have access to it in the html: {{form.yes_no}} My check mark.

What I want to do now take a list of strings over to the init and use that list to generate a list of booleans who's labels are the values of the strings in the list I passed over. Then take that form object pass it over to my view and html so when I look at the page I see a list of boolean objects with their labels and check boxes, basically a check list. I know how to do this in pure html, I am having some issues deciphering it using this Form class in python though. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright well I pieced this together, I started with a pretty basic form in my form.py:

```
class General_Form(Form):
    def validate(self):
        if not Form.validate(self):
            return False
        return True
```

my view.py route method brought that form over, and had

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if request.form['submit'] == "Find":
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            ----->> do stuff
```

with an element in my  that has:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Find"/>
```

Apparently, trying to use the class object constructors under Form class is only necessary if you are going to do a lot of complex things with it like check strings for malicious content, if you are just building an list of check boxes with a submit input then all those other constructors are not only not necessary, but it doesn't seem like there is a coherent way to even build them.